# datepicker is not showing timepicker inside

Tags: php, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)  I am inserting a user data when user have to select date and time from `datepiker`.

My problem is `date-piker` is showing properly but it didn't show `time-piker` inside it.

```
$('body').on('focus',"#arrival_date_time", function(){
     $(this).datepicker({   
          timePicker: true,
          timePickerIncrement: 30,      
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
          autoclose: true
     });
});
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
    <input class="form-control" required id="arrival_date_time" name="arrival_date_time" type="text">
</div>
```

My Datepiker is inside the bootstrap model. is this `model` creating a problem? 
Here is the Image of What I am getting.

[image: Date & Time Error]

Comment: model may create problem, make sure that JS code is fired after model is shown.

Comment: Thanks I have checked it, it is ok because datepiker is working fine.  so i think it was not the problem.